# Is it possible to build a Survival Games server that has multiple games running at once?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-spigot

How do I make Survival games have more than one game at a time on Spigot? I am using a dedicated server for Survival Games.

Comment: Can you clarify this a bit? What do you mean multiple games? Multiple worlds? What have you tried so far?

Comment: [this](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/multiverse-core.390/)?

Comment: Have you tried searching google for 'Multi-world plugins spigot'? You can find multiple plugins within 10 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Host two servers at once. Make sure you edit the server.properties for the second server, to run on a different port (default is 25565).
2. Host a server with multiple worlds. I would recommend a plugin like [Multiverse](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/multiverse-core.390/). It uses less resources than hosting a second server, and allows you to create as many worlds as you like. You can make new worlds for players to warp between, and you can even set per-inventory worlds, so players will not be able to transfer their items to another world.

If you decide to go for Multiverse, you may want to install [Multiverse-Portals](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/multiverse-portals/) as well. This allows you to create portals for players to walk through, rather than having your players having to fiddle with commands.

Answer (score 0):

The 'Ultimate Survival Games' Bukkit plugin allows multiple arenas to be defined in the same world; in this way, you can have one lobby and then several Arenas (separate them by a couple of hundred empty blocks) all working independently.